# Как изменить пространство имен у формы Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Работаю над проектом средней крупности в Visual Studio 2019.
Количество форм проекта дошло до "неудобного", и решил я их раскидать по папкам (сразу не додумался). Дело в том что пространство имен существующих форм не поменялось (имя_проекта), а вот когда я создаю новую форму в конкретной папке, то ее пространство имен прописывается как "имя_проекта.имя_папки". Я бы хотел чтобы у всех форм в папке было такое пространство имен. Но меняя вручную начинается "красная площадь", студия громко ругается, но решений не предлагает.

Вопрос чисто этический, т.к. текущее состояние на работу приложения не влияет, но продолжать работать немного неприятно (у меня легкая степень ОКР, и когда что-то не так мне это мешает сосредоточиться).

Comment: Кое-что можно исправить поиском и заменой (Find and Replace) по всему решению. / Многие проблемы может исправить Resharper (но он платный). / Есть и бесплатные расширения для Студии: [NamespaceFixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=p2410.NamespaceFixer), [Fix Namespace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-599079.FixNamespace). Можете попытать удачу с ними. Если что, удалить их всегда можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сдаётся мне, что Вы меняете пространство имён только в коде с логикой формы. Есть ещё файл с кодом дизайнера. И вряд ли ошибусь если у Вас есть ещё операторы `using` в других классах, которые задействуют эти формы...

То, что Вы взялись за рефакторинг разросшегося проекта, в этом нет ничего страшного. Но, если Вы поменяли пространство имён у формы в одном месте, то Вам нужно будет поменять его везде.

Comment: Точно, про код дизайнера забыл. Спасибо.